# Why is load average being reported as 0.00 though system is busy doing work?

Tags: top, uptime, load-average

`uptime`, `top`, `cat /proc/loadavg` all reporting load averages for the last 1/5/15 minutes as `0.00`, but the system is definitely busy doing work. Why is this? Server is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6, kernel 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64.

```
$ uptime
 12:13:44 up 73 days, 8 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

$ cat /proc/loadavg
 0.00 0.00 0.00 12/2706 39700

$ top
top - 12:15:35 up 73 days, 10 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 572 total,   4 running, 568 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 37.1%us,  2.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 42.0%id, 18.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.5%si,  0.0%st
...
```

Comment: load average has always been the least reliable indicator of a system load in my experience. It's really hard to read and understand.

Comment: ...but I've found it to the best indicator of system stress / CPU bottlenecks

Answer (score 1):

Load averages only account for processes in the **running** state and the values may very well be under 0.01. 
More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987495/linux-proc-loadavg

A bug is also a possibility ;)

Answer (score 0):

While both the load and CPU metrics you have quoted here are averaged over a period, they are averaged over DIFFERENT periods. CPU usage is calculated between top refreshes (3 seconds here) while load over 1,5 and 10 minutes